# Number of possible combinations on 2 sets where 1 set have 2 types

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

I am trying to create a formula to represent the cards against humanity game https://cardsagainsthumanity.com/ where I can calculate the quantity of possible combination between questions cards and answers cars so we have two sets that can be combined:

Questions
Answers

but Questions have two types of cards, one that accepts 1 answer it means a combination Question - Answer and one that accepts 2 answers Question - (AnswerA - AnswerB).

I am trying to find a formula to understand how many available combinations could be depending on the quantity of answers, the quantity that need one answer and question that need two answers.

Comment: What do you mean by a "combination" in this context?  A question/answer pair (*or question/answer1/answer2 pair in for the pick2 cards?*).  Define your variables.  Let $p$ be the number of questions taking one answer, $q$ the number of questions taking two answers, $a$ the number of answer cards.  There are $p\cdot a+q\cdot a\cdot (a-1)$ possible q/a(/a) combinations.

Comment: This comes from a combination of understanding of the [rule of sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_sum) and [rule of product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_product)